# echo javascript with php

Tags: javascript, php, alert

i tried to echo javascript with php.

```
    if(isset($_GET['question'])) {
    $question = $_GET['question'];
    echo '
    <script>
    var r = confirm("sind Sie sicher, dass sie den Patienten entfernen wollen? Der Vorgang kann nicht rückgängig gemacht werder! Außerdem könnte es Fehler in der Vergebung der KundenIDs verursachen!");
    if (r == true) {
        x = "self.location.href='; echo "'overviewPatienten.php?KID_uebergabe_del=".$question."'";
    echo'
    }</script>';
    }
```

i tried to run this code (index.php?question=1) but the alert box doesn't apear.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Error in the console?

Comment: I think you have some quotes overriding eachother. Can you see if the script tag is formatted properly in the elements panel?

Comment: Pop up blocker? Do you see the code when you view source?

Comment: no, popups are allowed. In examples where I just wrote the javascript it worked

Comment: View the page source, the script you echo, is it there?

Comment: Just close the PHP with `?>` when you have this much HTML/JS to output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why so many echo commands? You are just going to confuse yourself and have some syntax error... how about:

```
echo '
    <script>
    var r = confirm("sind Sie sicher, dass sie den Patienten entfernen wollen? Der Vorgang kann nicht rückgängig gemacht werder! Außerdem könnte es Fehler in der Vergebung der KundenIDs verursachen!");
    if (r == true) {
        x = "self.location.href=\'overviewPatienten.php?KID_uebergabe_del='.$question.'\'";
    }
    </script>';
```

Comment: thank you your code worked! :)

Comment: Your welcome. You should have viewed the page source to check that your output was syntactically correct and would have spotted that you missed out the end of the command within the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript in PHP using this syntax.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'document.write("Hello World!")';
echo '</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in a bit different way: using ajax call.

for example:

```
        $.ajax({
        url:'index.php',
        data: "question="+TheQuestionNumbr,
        success: function(res){
            if(res){
            yourJavascriptFunction();
            }

        },
        error: function(res){
            alert('Some error message via javascript here or echoed error message using res:'+res);
        }
        });
```

So you don't need to run echoed script in this way: you just receive echoed parameter and do accordingly to its value.

Is it clear? Can you use things in this way?

Answer (score -1):

- Your HTML has `<meta charset="utf-8">`?

  - Try out `<script type="text/javascript">` instead of `<script>`
  - Change this `x= ="self.location.href...` for this `x = "self.location.href...`

I hope this helps :)